# Inkscape - Controlling BSPline for Path Effects

Tags: inkscape

If I design a square in Inkscape and apply **Path effects** on it and use **BSpline** to curve the *top two* corners of my square, what is the "correct" process to get the roundness applied and controlled on my top two corners (**while keeping the bottom corners and sides perfectly straight**)?

The settings seems to give either a very dramatic rounded effect, or a very insignificant amount.  Plus when you press CTRL and click to drag the little node items, they stop as a certain point.  Very frustrating.   **What is the proper way to control round corners in this case for my top two corners of a square.**

I want to do something easily like this with Path Effects in Inkscape....

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to use BSplines for this now. The following is for Inkscape 1.0 and later, and uses the new Live Path Effects (LPE) feature.

1. Draw a rectangle without any rounded corners, and make sure it is selected.
2. Open the Path Effects panel <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>&</kbd>, hit the Plus icon to add a new path effect, and type "Corners" in the search, and choose the *Corners (Fillet/Chamfer)* effect.

[image]

3. In the Path Effects panel, set the radius you want, then using the Edit Paths by Nodes tool <kbd>N</kbd>, click and drag the corner controls back inwards towards the corners to make them sharp.
4. If you want to convert the LPE effect to an actual path, then select the object and do *Path > Object to Path*, otherwise skip this.

Example:

[image]

Comment: Billy Kerr you are the man.  Thank you soooo much for your insight and sharing it on this post!